# How to prevent pd.ewma from changing the index?

Tags: python, time-series, pandas

I am resampling my time series data using the following code:

```
bars = transactions.price.resample('4H', base = 3).ohlc()
```

This allows me to account for DST correctly. The output is:

```
timestamp
2017-12-31 07:00:00    12668.5
2017-12-31 11:00:00    13183.0
2017-12-31 15:00:00    13124.0
2017-12-31 19:00:00    13178.5
2017-12-31 23:00:00    13130.5
```

I now want to calculate moving average using pandas .rolling function and trying the following:

```
ma_rolling = pd.ewma(bars['close'], span=20, freq='4H')
```

This messes up the time interval, shifting it to even hours:

```
timestamp
2017-12-31 04:00:00    14006.251358
2017-12-31 08:00:00    13927.838526
2017-12-31 12:00:00    13851.275461
2017-12-31 16:00:00    13787.196295
2017-12-31 20:00:00    13724.649100
```

Is it possible to specify a base / shift in ewma functions and to preserve the original indices? The .rolling function does not act like this and preserves original indices.